# rails simple_form_for vs. form_for value/title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have the following line in simple form:

```
 <%= f.input :profile_name, label: false,
   input_html: {:title => "Enter Username",  :class => "field"} %>
```

This outputs:

```
<div class="input string required user_profile_name">
    <input id="user_profile_name" class="string required field" type="text"
      title="Enter Username" size="50" required="required" name="user[profile_name]"
      maxlength="50" aria-required="true">
    </input>
</div>
```

I have a regular form line that should be the same as the simple form line:

```
<%= f.text_field :profile_name, :title => "Enter Username", :class => "field" %>
```

It outputs:

```
<input id="user_profile_name" class="field" type="text" value="Enter Username"
  title="Enter Username" name="user[profile_name]">
</input>
```

The regularform behaves the right way.  The text "Enter Username", which is inside the input field, disappears when clicked on, reappears if nothing is typed, and goes away when something else is typed in.  How can I get the simple_form to behave that way?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your requirement you are looking for a HTML5 `placeholder` attribute.  To use it with `simple_form`, try this:

```
<%= f.input :profile_name, label: false,
   input_html: {:placeholder => "Enter Username",  :class => "field"} %>
```

Please reference [simple_form home page](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) for further documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the placeholder attribute but it does not disappear upon clicking like title does with regular forms.